# How to add hostname, date, and fix disk size

Tags: text-processing, awk, disk-usage, text-formatting

I'm collecting disk usage data and want to add the date, time, and hostname to this command. How can I do it in this format:

```
 YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS,HOSTNAME,DISK_USAGE_DATA
```

Command I have so far:

```
 df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $2 "," $3 "," $4 "," $1 }'
```

Also, how can I get the output of the command to provide me the size in KB instead of the mixed GB/MB by default? That way I have a base to work off of when computing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` can do that all alone:

```
df -B KB | awk 'NR!=1&&$1!~/tmpfs|cdrom/{printf "'$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")','$(hostname)',%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $2, $3, $4, $1}'
```

Explanation:

- `df -B KB`: prints the values in KB
- `awk`

  - `NR!=1`: avoid the first line
  - `$1!~/tmpfs|cdrom/`: if the first field contains not the excluded filsystems
  - `printf`: print formatted
  - `$(date +%Y-%m-%d)`: the date in the desired format
  - `$(hostname)`: the hostname
  - `%s,%s,%s,%s\n`: and the rest

Comment: How can I have the date/time with a space between instead of the hyphen after %d ? I get a run away error message if I remove the - and put a space.

Comment: Figured it out, seems awk doesn't accept spaces. So I just used the date command twice to run date and time separately.

Comment: @linguru772x  `|sed -e "s/,/ /g"` add at the end the line, help you ? Remose the `g` if you only want remove the first `,`